# Adding previous value column in Power Bi for 80.000 rows

Tags: powerbi, data-modeling

I am adding custom column with this formula   `try #"Added Custom" { [Index] -1 } [Action Type] otherwise null`
that show previous value. It is show normal way [image]
But when I am trying to close & apply I got stuck with loading [image]

My data is not that huge. Sth like 80.000 rows and 25 columns.